# SplitView In Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want my `SplitView` to be invisible in its compact state. But a large width is taken by it even in the compact state and open state.

```
<SplitView x:Name="svNav" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
    <SplitView.Content>
        <StackPanel Width="0" />
    </SplitView.Content>
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid Name="lbPane" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView>
                <TextBlock FontSize="24">Mode</TextBlock>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" VerticalAlignment="Center">&#xE80F;</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0">Standard Mode</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" VerticalAlignment="Center">&#xE1E9;</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0">Scientific Mode</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" VerticalAlignment="Center">&#xE117;</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0">Converter</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" VerticalAlignment="Center">&#xE8EB;</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0">Programming Mode</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Pane>
</SplitView>
```

There is a problem in the design. Please look at what can be done to resolve the 
[Preview of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z2H2.png)

Comment: I see no issue with this. Where are your adaptive states xaml? Can you post the complete xaml?

Comment: Did you see picture using the line (Preview of the application). There is no adaptive states yet? Is it necessary?

Comment: The XAML is too long to show? But I can tell you that splitview is in a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Split view should be the root element the page and grid should be units content.